# WCF service is not working in browser hosted from a console

Tags: c#, wcf

I have created a simple WCF service in windows console (Learning purpose).

The service is able to consume using code (using same url) but unable to discover in another project/solution or not able to browse the url in browser.

I'm **not** using any config file. So what I have to do to discover/ browse the service?

I'm using c#.net and referring System.ServiceModel

My code is below

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;

[ServiceContract]
interface IMyservice
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetResult(string value1, string value2);
}
class My Service : IMyService
{
    string GetResult(string value1, string value2)
    {
        return $"First Name : {value1}\nLast Name : {value2}";
    }
}
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var host = new ServiceHost(typeOf(MyService));
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeOf(IMyService), new BasicHttpBinding(), "http://localhost:1234/service1");
        host.open();
        
        var service = new ChannelFactory<IMyService>.CreateChannel(new BasicHtpBinding(), new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:1234/service1"));
        Console.WriteLine(service.GetResult("Ragesh", "Sivakumar"));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: _"...but unable to discover in another project/solution..."_ - do you mean via Visual Studio's **Add service reference**?

Comment: **Yes**  @MickyD

Comment: You just need to expose WCF Service Metadata via code. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-publish-metadata-for-a-service-using-code

Comment: @MickyD - **It is working**, I'm able to browse and discover the methods when adding the service. I'll add the answer below. So, for learning WCF which is the best tutorial available? Do u have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

So, for getting the service in browser and discovering the service in service reference you have to add ServiceMetadataBehavior like below,

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var host = new ServiceHost(typeOf(MyService));
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeOf(IMyService), new BasicHttpBinding(), "http://localhost:1234/service1");
        
        ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
        host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName, MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(), "mex");
        host.open();
        
        var service = new ChannelFactory<IMyService>.CreateChannel(new BasicHtpBinding(), new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:1234/service1"));
        Console.WriteLine(service.GetResult("Ragesh", "Sivakumar"));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```